# form_for for nested routes which namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following three models:

Article
Article::Line (lines of the article)
Article::Review  (reviews of a line)

I want to have a route that is

/articles/11/line/2/review/new
/articles/11/line/2/review/edit

My route.rb

```
  resources :articles do
    scope module: 'article' do
      resources :lines do
        resources :reviews
      end
    end
  end
```

I am trying to make the form_for work with both new and edit automatically:

```
<%= form_for [ @line.article, @line, @review ] do |f| %>
```

However this will produce **undefined method `article_article_line_article_reviews_path'** error.

What have I done wrong, or is this possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using `scope module` syntax, but what if you try this? `<%= form_for [ @line.article, :article, @line, @review ] do |f| %>`

Comment: @ChrisPeters It would become `article_article_article_line_article_reviews_path`, one more article